# Mock location.href in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing Jasmin testcases for a parameter method and it looks some thing like this

$scope.getparam( function(){
HREF= location.href
....
})

I am writing testcases for this
Locally the location.href is local host://context.html

I want location.href different url
How can I mock location.href

Answer (score 0):

No need to mock location.href. You can directly assign value to it and it will redirect you to particular location as mentioned by you.

```
location.href = "https://www.google.com"
```